query and add group column that represent a dynamic bulk of rows
Given a table with 10000 rows. I want to split the rows to 9 segments each of 10000/9 rows. (all numbers are dynamic 42987/14 for example). So I want my select query results to look like. I am using BigQuery



row number
segment
Other headers




1
1
other columns


2
1
other columns


...
...
...


1111
1
other columns


1112
2
other columns


1113
2
other columns


...
...
...


9999
9
other columns


10000
10
other columns




You can try using ROW_NUMBER and NTILE Window Functions for this. Although you haven't specified any kind of ordering(what row comes first, what comes last etc). Ordering is usually done based on the value of another column.

There is a timestamp column. RowNumber can also be used for this.
Ordering don't matter.

This did the trick
 WITH
   raw AS (
   SELECT
     *
   FROM
     `table_to_segment` ),
   params AS (
   SELECT
     9 AS hours )
 SELECT
   *,
   CAST(CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() / ((
         SELECT
           COUNT(*)
         FROM
           raw) / (
         SELECT
           hours
         FROM
           params))) AS INT64) AS segment
 FROM
   raw

